# MVC login form editing database

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Im trying to modify the LogIn page in the MVC 5 default project. I want to add the role to the table username and password (table AspNetUsers) but I can't find where this table is created.
The user should be redirected to another page depending on the role. How could that happen???

Comment: how to modify database?Is't there a database (tables) creation in MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search on `google` and `stackoverflow,` I found this answer which I think is correct answer to your question.

"Upon registering the first user a database named ASPNETDB.MDF under the application’s App_Data directory is created. This information was supplied by default in the root web.config file."

There is no default `login` or a `database` when you create a new project in mvc, once you register your first user using the `"Register"` a db file will be created in the `App_Data` folder.

***Please note* The link may become out of use in the future.**
[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781860/default-login-asp-net-mvc3)

Comment: Is the answer helpful? @mohammad